# Android SDK tools and ADT version missmatch

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I updated Android SDK Tools version 22.6.1 for Android Wear but not able to upgrade the ADT. 
I tried Help > Check for updates, but it doesn't show any updates. 
Moreover, it fails to build older projects as it requires new ADT v22.6 for SDK Tools v22.6.1

Any idea why I am not getting latest ADT and how to solve it ?

Edit: 
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ is already there in update sites.

Comment: In Eclipse, open the SDK Manager (via toolbar or Window menu) > Tools > Manager AVDs. This will invoke the external version of the AVD Manager which will properly generate AVDs. Other workaround: use the command-line version (Shell or cmd.exe, cd SDK, "tools\android.bat avd")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow these steps:

1. Help > Install new software
2. Select the ADT update site (there are two, one with Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and one with Android Developer Tools Update Site - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ If one doesn't work, try the other).
3. Select the developer tools section and press next.
4. You should see a dialog that says "this software is already installed, an update will be performed instead". Clicking ok will lead to 22.6.1 being installed.

check this link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67325

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse->help->install new software->Add
 in location  use https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ url to update your Adt

Comment: That is already there. My question is, despite it there, it doesn't show any updates available. While in-fact it should have update available.